# Bootstrap 3 Aligning Two Divs Horizontally

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I'm planning to align these to two divs(the ones containing h3 tags) horizontally but every time I resize my browser the other div keeps on stacking below the first div. Here's a part of the code. Where did I do wrong?

```
<section id="main-content" " ng-controller="studCtrl">
      <section class="wrapper">
        <h3><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Administrative Module</h3>
          <div class="row mt">
              <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="content-panel">
                    <div class="container-fixed">
                        <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-6 ">
                                    <h3>Lost and Found List</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <h3 class="text-right">Button here</h3>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                                <thead>
                                  <tr >
                                      ...
                                  </tr>
                                 </thead>
                                 <tbody>
                                   ...
                                 </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>

               </div><!-- /content-panel -->
           </div><!-- /col-lg-12 -->
          </div><!--/row mt -->

         </section><!--/wrapper -->
  </section><!-- /MAIN CONTENT -->
```

Comment: Probably unrelated, but you started off with a typo. Extra quote in `<section id="main-content" " ng-controller="studCtrl">`

Comment: oh sorry about that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely it's your browser resizing is not going beyond the media query widths for the 'large' column definitions. Try the xs or sm instead to find the desired breaks.

```
<div class="col-xs-6"> ... </div>
```

The above would always break 2 columns.

The link below shows the details of the media queries underlying. For this answer, the relevant breaks are:

```
Prefix      Break
.col-xs-    auto
.col-sm-    ~372px/col-6 (750px for container)
.col-md-    ~486px/col-6 (970px for container)
.col-lg-    ~582px/col-6 (1170px for container)
```

Link: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries

Answer (score 0):

You have to see how aspects of the Bootstrap grid system work across multiple devices with a handy table. [Grid options](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)

Grid classes apply to devices with screen widths **greater than or equal** to the breakpoint sizes, and override grid classes targeted at smaller devices. Therefore, e.g. applying any .col-md-* class to an element will not only affect its styling on medium devices but also on large devices if a .col-lg-* class is not present.

- **col-xs-*** for extra small devices Phones (<768px)
- **col-sm-*** for small devices Tablets (≥768px)
- **col-md-*** for medium devices Desktops (≥992px)
- **col-lg-*** Large devices Desktops (≥1200px)

Thus, you must change your code to these below:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
   <h3>Lost and Found List</h3>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
   <h3 class="text-right">Button here</h3>
</div>
```

Or, incase if you want two divs always horizontal even for mobile device.

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
   <h3>Lost and Found List</h3>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
   <h3 class="text-right">Button here</h3>
</div>
```